# Resize images in Flex using as3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image, flex3, resize

I am  loading an image using a Loader. Once loaded, I can get the bitmap data using `Bitmap(event.target.loader.content).bitmapData`.

However since the images I am loading are quite large (around 2000 x 1600), I would like to reduce the size and create a new smaller bitmap maybe 200 or 300 pixels wide, sort of like a thumbnail.

I think it has to do with creating a new `BitmapData` with the new size. However I am not able to get that working properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I feel like this is a bit of a waste to load that large image and only have it resized.  It's useless data.  Can't you have a server resize it for you when it's requested?

Comment: actually i cant have it re sized from the server, plus it seems i am unable to load an image from the server directly, getting a security exception. I don't have control over the server and i am just using data that is available publicly.

Comment: You could always create a middleware server (php or something) to do the resizing for you, relieving the client to load up a very large image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not tested, but this should give you an idea:

```
public function scaleBitmap(src: BitmapData, ratio: Number): BitmapData
{
    var bmd: BitmapData = new BitmapData(src.width * ratio, src.height * ratio);
    var m: Matrix = new Matrix();   
    m.scale(ratio, ratio);
    bmd.draw(src, m);
    return bmd;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this code from the BitmapImage class. I've updated it to support the drawWithQuality method of the BitmapData class. See the StageQuality class for values.

Note: You'll need to set the SWF version to at least 16 to use the quality API. However, the compiler doesn't seem to throw an error either way.

```
    /**
     * @private
     * Utility function used for higher quality image scaling. Essentially we
     * simply step down our bitmap size by half resulting in a much higher result
     * though taking potentially multiple passes to accomplish.
     * 
     * source spark.primitives.BitmapImage
     */
    protected static function resample(bitmapData:BitmapData, newWidth:uint,
                                       newHeight:uint, quality:String = null):BitmapData
    {

        var finalScale:Number = Math.max(newWidth/bitmapData.width,
            newHeight/bitmapData.height);

        var finalData:BitmapData = bitmapData;

        // ERROR HERE MEANS
        // Property drawWithQuality not found on flash.display.BitmapData and there is no default value.
        // 
        // Solution
        // add -swf-version=16 or greater to your compiler arguments
        // 
        // https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3219149
        if (finalScale > 1)
        {
            finalData = new BitmapData(bitmapData.width * finalScale,
                bitmapData.height * finalScale, true, 0);

            if (quality) {
                finalData.drawWithQuality(bitmapData, new Matrix(finalScale, 0, 0,
                    finalScale), null, null, null, true, quality);
            }
            else {
                finalData.draw(bitmapData, new Matrix(finalScale, 0, 0,
                    finalScale), null, null, null, true);
            }

            return finalData;
        }

        var drop:Number = .5;
        var initialScale:Number = finalScale;

        while (initialScale/drop < 1)
            initialScale /= drop;

        var w:Number = Math.floor(bitmapData.width * initialScale);
        var h:Number = Math.floor(bitmapData.height * initialScale);
        var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h, bitmapData.transparent, 0);

        if (quality) {
            bd.drawWithQuality(finalData, new Matrix(initialScale, 0, 0, initialScale),
                null, null, null, true, quality);
        }
        else {
            bd.draw(finalData, new Matrix(initialScale, 0, 0, initialScale),
                null, null, null, true);
        }

        finalData = bd;

        for (var scale:Number = initialScale * drop;
            Math.round(scale * 1000) >= Math.round(finalScale * 1000);
            scale *= drop)
        {
            w = Math.floor(bitmapData.width * scale);
            h = Math.floor(bitmapData.height * scale);
            bd = new BitmapData(w, h, bitmapData.transparent, 0);


            if (quality) {
                bd.drawWithQuality(finalData, new Matrix(drop, 0, 0, drop), null, null, null, true, quality);
            }
            else {
                bd.draw(finalData, new Matrix(drop, 0, 0, drop), null, null, null, true);
            }

            finalData.dispose();
            finalData = bd;
        }

        return finalData;
    }
```

And to use it:

```
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = resample(sourceBitmapData, desiredWidth, desiredHeight, StageQuality.HIGH_16X16);
```