# Flex: How to resize images?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I tried multiple ways of doing that but it is not working. My application allows user to upload multiple images then user can resize selected images by click of one button.
**Code:**

```
public function resizeImage():void
{ 
  var tempArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(listOfSelectedImages.source);
                var originalImage:Image = tempArray.getItemAt(0) as Image;
                var resizedImage:Image = new Image();
                var resizeObj:Resize = new Resize();

                resizedImage = originalImage;

                /* for each(var originalImage:Object in tempArray)
                { */

                //}
                resizedImage.maxWidth = 470
                resizedImage.maxHeight = 394;
                resizedImage.smooth = true;
                saveFiles(resizedImage);
            }

            private function saveFiles(image:Image):void
            {
                    //var image:Image = resizedArray.getItemAt(0) as Image;
                    var byteArray:ByteArray = convertImageToByteArray(image.source);
                    fileReference.save(byteArray, image.name.split(".")[0]+".jpeg");
            }
```

I tried to change resize logic using Resize effect component:

```
var resizeObj:Resize = new Resize();

                resizedImage = originalImage;
                resizeObj.widthTo=470;
                resizeObj.heightTo = 394;
                resizeObj.widthFrom = originalImage.width;
                resizeObj.heightFrom = originalImage.height;
                resizeObj.target = resizedImage;

                resizeObj.end();
                resizeObj.play();
                /* for each(var originalImage:Object in tempArray)
                { */

                //}

                resizedImage.smooth = true;
```

But nothing work for me.

> > Here I am trying to resize one image for testing but finally I will be resizing multiple image.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623739/514087) from [Resize images in Flex using as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623529/resize-images-in-flex-using-as3):

```
public function scaleBitmap(src: BitmapData, ratio: Number): BitmapData
{
    var bmd: BitmapData = new BitmapData(src.width * ratio, src.height * ratio);
    var m: Matrix = new Matrix();   
    m.scale(ratio, ratio);
    bmd.draw(src, m);
    return bmd;
}
```

Then your loop would look like:

```
var scaleWanted:Number = 0.5; //get the real ratio desired from user input
var originalImages:ArrayCollection; //set this from selected images
var resizedImages:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for each (var img:Image in originalImages) {
    var resizedData:BitmapData = scaleBitmap(img.bitmapData), scaleWanted);
    var alteredImage:Image = new Image();
    alteredImage.source = resizedData;
    resizedImages.push(alteredImage);
}
//next up, save the resized images to disk.
```

Comment: Line `var alteredImage:Image = new Image(resizedData);` gives me error. I am using Spark image component.

Comment: Ah, in that case you'd set the `source` property instead.  I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I have got that resolved. Now the issue is the way how image get resized. Resized image's center gets stretched.